# Is it possible to have a Windows app that does not have an icon or tray icon but run in the background?

Tags: windows

I am just wondering if it is even possible to code a Windows app that will run in the background but have no icon or tray icon?  Related to this https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/9526

So far from what I can tell this is only possible if the app was converted to a "service" which then leads to the question... can a service interact with the desktop environment without an app which from what I can tell requires an icon to indicate that it is running.

Answer (score 1):

Tray icon is **never** automatic. It's displayed on purpose, willingly, and you must add code to have a working drop-down menu on it. Most applications don't even have a tray icon. For memory, tray icons are the ones at right-end of taskbar, near the clock.

It's different for the *taskbar* icon, the "main" ones. These ones are automatically present when an application creates a **normal** main window, even it it's minimized.
To avoid this, your main window should be created with `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended style instead.

Please look at [Taskbar documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar#managing-taskbar-buttons) for details - windows's ownership plays a great role, too.

Please note that adapting that to a graphical framework (like Qt) can be non-trivial, since the windows must be *created* with this flag - and not just have this flag set later.

Comment: I'm asking specifically whether an app can exist without NEITHER tray NOR app icon.

Comment: Yes, and isn't it clear enough? Answer is "YES". Tray icon is something you MUST PROGRAM. So don't do it, and no tray icon. For the taskbar icon, I told you how it works for NOT having one.

Comment: And BTW, a service usually can't interact with desktop, so making a service won't help. At all. Only way is the one I put in my answer: build your app this way, launch it, you'll have neither taskbar icon nor tray icon. Read the doc I linked to understand WHY you have a taskbar icon.